# can a for loop run more than the specified time

Tags: singly-linked-list

Every time I run this program the output is not correct and also the for loop is running an extra time, please help me out.And if possible please explain why am i getting addresses when I display the linked list elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *nxt;
}node;
node* createnode(int n);
void display(node *head);
int main()
{
    int n;
    node *head=NULL;
    printf("\nno of nodes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    head=createnode(n);
    display(head);
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

//program to create a new node

```
node* createnode(int n)
{
    node *head=NULL;
    node *temp=NULL;
    node *p;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the data for node ",i);
        scanf("%d",&temp->info);
        temp->nxt=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p=head;
            while(p->nxt!=NULL)
            p=p->nxt;
            p->nxt=temp;
        }
    }
    return head;

}//program to display the elements stored in linkedlist
void display(node *head)
{
    node *p=head;
    while(p !=NULL)
    {
        printf("\t %d",p->info);
        p=p->nxt;
    }  
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have for these problems?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuvJu.png

Comment: That image does not match the posted code.

Comment: but i have sent you the output of the same code

Comment: `printf("Enter the data for node ",i);` should produce a space after `node` (an a warning that there is an extra argument).

Comment: i tried to compile after removing this i but it is still not happening